# Determine the hostnames of IP conflict

Tags: arp

I have a network with several hundred machines on it. I have a machine that gives intermittent connectivity issues, reported via vSphere web client. This troublesome machine has the hostname "vsphere01".

I throw a crash cart on "vsphere01" and it reports that arp has detected a duplicate IP on the network, which is conflicting with the current IP of "vsphere01". It reports the mac address of the (as of now, unknown) machine with the duplicate IP.

Here is my question:
How can I tell my local workstation (running debian Linux) that I would like to treat the mac address of the as yet unknown machine as the correct mac address to be used for this duplicate ip? My goal is to be able to ssh to this unknown machine and determine the hostname. I am assuming that this should be possible, as the arp table on my local machine is just a table of ips that correspond to mac addresses, if I understand correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: This is really a question for Serverfault.com.  You're much more likely to get an answer there.

Answer (score 5):

`arp -d ip-address` to delete the existing entry if it's there.

`arp -s ip-address mac-address` to manually set a new arp entry.

`man arp` if you want more detail.